# Action only when new post is published

Tags: wordpress

I'm writing plugin for myself and I need some function to fire off when new post is published. So far I found http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions which says that there is action for each pair of statuses. I want to know which action function should fire off. I tried `new_to_publish` (didn't fire off)  and `draft_to_publish` (worked as intended) and  `auto-draft_to_publish` (worked half intended. was able to get ID from global post variable (to get link via get_permalink()) but title (in post variable) was set to Auto Draft instead of actual title.
So question is, what action should I actually use? I assume it should be both `auto-draft_to_publish` and `draft_to_publish` but in that was I want to know how to get actual title instead of Auto Draft

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use `auto-draft_to_publish` and `draft_to_publish`. First happens when totally new post is published, second happens when draft is published. I didn't notice at first that both pass $post variable (I used global $post first time which caused "Auto Draft" title).
With this my problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Use the publish_post and publish_future_post actions.

As you would expect, these fire when a post is published and when it is triggered to publish if set to a future date.

EDIT:

To make sure that the post is being published check the modified date with the post date.

```
function publishing_post( $post_id ) {
  $post = get_post( $post_id );

    if( $post->post_modified <> $post->post_date ) return;

}
```

Comment: publish_post triggers action when post is also updated which in my case is unacceptable and not needed.

Comment: Edited answer to further assist.

Comment: @Flyer - the fact that it is triggeres also on update does not keep you from USING it to check for other conditions like Mark suggested ..